# How to customize form with bootstrap with django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

How would I customize a select for a foreignkey in bootstrap?

For example,

```
class SolarSystem(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(...)
      description = models.CharField(...)

class Planet(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(...)
      solarsystem = models.ForeignKey(SolarSystem)
```

I want to build a planet form where I can select a solar system. The solarsystem should be a bootstrap select (ie, class="form-control"). Sometimes the options may have some description which I want to display.

ie, some pseudocode:

```
<select class="form-control">
    {% for option in planet.solarsystem: %}

         <option>
              {{ option.name }}
              {{ if option.description != null: }}
                  <span class="select-description">{{option.description}}</span>
         </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Is there a way to do this directly in the template without resorting to defining my own widget specifically for a solarsystem foreignkey?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/) as it is a more complete solution to rendering forms in Bootstrap templates.

With crispy forms, you just need to use a plain Django form and a few lines of template code like:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    {{ my_form|crispy }}
</form>
```

Comment: Even with crispy-forms, how would I add in the logic of displaying the solarsystem description?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<option>` like so:

```
<option>
    {{ option.name }}
    {% if option.description %}
        <span class="select-description">{{ option.description }}</span>
    {% endif %}
</option>
```